# Parsing string from protected void onCreate method to public class main activity

Tags: java, android, json

I have declared strings string1, string2, string3, string4.. string7 in public class. and I am getting values from MySQL database using JSON in onCreate method and storing in String variables st1 , st2, st3...., st7.

Now I need to pass these st1 ,st2,st3,...,st7 values to the string1, string2, string3... string7 respectively.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity;

private CoordinatorLayout mCLayout;
private Button mButtonDo;
private TextView mTextView;
private String mJSONURLString = "http://paolo.....";

String string1, string2, string3, string4, string4, string5, string6, string7;

String seats = string1 + "" + string2 + "" + string3 + "" + string4 + "" + string5 + "" + string6 + "" + string7;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mActivity = MainActivity.this;

    mCLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    mTextView.setText("");

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, mJSONURLString, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray seat) {

                    try {
                        // Loop through the array elements
                        for (int i = 0; i < seat.length(); i++) {
                            // Get current json object
                            JSONObject student = seat.getJSONObject(i);

                            String st1 = student.getString("st1");
                            String st2 = student.getString("st2");
                            String st3 = student.getString("st3");
                            String st4 = student.getString("st4");

                            String st5 = student.getString("st5");
                            String st6 = student.getString("st6");
                            String st7 = student.getString("st7");

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}
```

}

Comment: And ? What is the problem here ? Just change `strX' into `stringX` in your `OnResponse()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the elements in the for loop as you are doing :

```
String st1 = student.getString("st1");
String st2 = student.getString("st2");
String st3 = student.getString("st3");
String st4 = student.getString("st4");
String st5 = student.getString("st5");
String st6 = student.getString("st6");
String st7 = student.getString("st7");
```

You should change it to  :

```
string1 = student.getString("st1");
string2 = student.getString("st2");
string3 = student.getString("st3");
string4 = student.getString("st4");
string5 = student.getString("st5");
string6 = student.getString("st6");
string7 = student.getString("st7");
```

And if you want to update UI or something just add the method inside the `onResponse()` I mean if you want to display that text you can create a

```
private void  showText(){
your_text_view1.setText(string1);
(....)
}
```

And then in the end of `onResponse()` just put this method.